# Allow only one div to have selected class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery in a form to select one of the uploaded images in a form to be the primary image. Essentially the user uploads up to 8 images on the previous step. They are then presented with thumbnails of the images, each has a corresponding hidden input with there value being the href to the image. The name of each input is galleryImage1, galleryImage2 and so on. What I would like to do is on click of one of the images the hidden input's name get's changed to primaryImage and a class of primaryImage is added. I have this working. However in this group of pictures only 1 is supposed to be selected. Right now you could pick all of them and the action would happen. How do I change this so this can only be applied to one image at a time. And then the catch is if the user changes their mind they could click a different image, the class and name would be removed, as well as the original name added to the hidden input from the first and added to the second choice.

html

```
<div class="outputimages">
    <div class="galleryImage">
        <img src="http://example.com/images/12345.png" name="galleryImage1">
        <input type="hidden" name="galleryImage1" data-origname="galleryImage1" value="12345.png">
    </div>
    <div class="galleryImage">
        <img src="http://example.com/images/123456.png" name="galleryImage2">
        <input type="hidden" name="galleryImage2" data-origname="galleryImage2" value="123456.png">
    </div>
    <div class="galleryImage">
        <img src="http://example.com/images/1234567.png" name="galleryImage3">
        <input type="hidden" name="galleryImage3" data-origname="galleryImage3" value="1234567.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

so if the first div was clicked on it would look like this

```
<div class="galleryImage primaryImage">
    <img src="http://example.com/images/12345.png" name="primaryImage">
    <input type="hidden" name="primaryImage" data-origname="galleryImage1" value="12345.png">
</div>
```

And on selection of the second div it would change back to original and the second div would get these changes. I have added the data-origname attribute so the name can be changed back.

my current js. These are dynamically generated items so I had to use .on to affect change.

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.galleryImage', function(){
    $(this).addClass('primaryImage');
    $(this).children().attr('name', 'primaryImage');    
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

First, let's think about the input naming and HTML structure.  Your current naming scheme doesn't scale.  I would suggest using array access notation like this:

```
<div class="galleryImage">
    <img src="http://example.com/images/12345.png">
    <input type="hidden" class="galleryImageInput" name="galleryImage[]" value="12345.png">
</div>
```

This removes the need to track `galleryImage1`, `galleryImage2`, etc. Note I have also added a class to the input to make selecting it easier and removed the `name` attribute from `<img>` (it is meaningless there). I have also removed the data attributes as they will no longer be needed as you will see.

Now, let's change the on-click handler:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.galleryImage', function(){
    // reset current primaryImage back to default
    $('.primaryImage')
        .removeClass('primaryImage')
        .find('.galleryImageInput')
        .attr('name', 'galleryImage[]');
    // set class and input name for clicked item
    $(this)
        .addClass('primaryImage')
        .find('.galleryImageInput')
        .attr('name', 'primaryImage');    
});
```

When POSTing the data, you will now have one input with name `primaryImage` and an array at the key `galleryImage`. This should make the data much easier to work with on the server side than having to deal individually with `galleryImage1`, `galleryImage2`, etc. and checking whether each has been converted to `primaryImage`.

Comment: $('galleryInput') missing a dot

Comment: I think $('.galleryImage').removeClass('primaryImage'); can be $('.primaryImage').removeClass('primaryImage'); a little more efficient

Comment: @Huangism I agree.  Same goes for the input name.

Comment: Probably won't matter too much now, I think OP has already implemented the solution

Comment: Just implemented this. It makes a lot more sense on post. I hadn't even thought of an array. I will mark this as my answer. Thanks for all the input. There are much smarter coders out there than me that's for sure.

Comment: @Huangism Well hopefully he can at least pick up the part about changing the HTML source.  Using array access notation would drastically improve his code.

Comment: @user1881482 Good to see you take this up.  Any time you see yourself making element id's, name's, etc. in the `sometext#` format, you should realize this is an anti-pattern and a better solution probably exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.galleryImage', function(){
    $('.galleryImage').removeClass('primaryImage');
    $('.galleryImage').children().each(function(i, el){
       $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('data-origname'));
    });
    $(this).addClass('primaryImage');
    $(this).children().attr('name', 'primaryImage');    
});
```

Comment: Yup, this works great. I originally was only trying to change the names of the input with the selected class. This is far better resets all to make sure. I will mark as answered.

Comment: instead of targeting all of the galleryImage can't you just target .primaryImage and update children, then remove class?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need something a bit more involved to truly restore the state, assuming you keep the HTML as is.

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.galleryImage', function () {
  var $this = $( this ),
      clss  = 'primaryImage',
      name  = $this.data( 'name' );
  // If name hasn't been fetched yet, fetch and store it
  if ( !name ) $this.data( 'name', $this.attr( 'name' ) );
  // Reset old element
  $this
    .siblings( '.' + clss )
    .removeClass( clss )
    .children()
    .attr( 'name', name );
  // Update new element
  $this
    .addClass( clss )
    .children()
    .attr( 'name', clss );
} );
```

Comment: It's strange you get the name using data but set the name using attr

Comment: This is for the first time hitting the element.  We store the initial name with data, so that we can revert it when it is un-selected.  It may be unnecessary, but assuming the galleryImage# initial names were needed, we would want to restore them.

Comment: oh nvm I was thinking of something else